# Multiple text-anchor styles for d3.axis text

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I have a straightforward axis setup:

```
var timelines = g2.selectAll(".timelines").data(data);

      var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(dataset)
        .range([0,axisSpacing.width]);

      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom")
          .ticks(1)
          .tickFormat(axisTicks)
          .outerTickSize(0)
          .tickSize(0);

      timelines.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis")
          .attr('transform',function(d,i) { return "translate(" + axisSpacing.left + "," + (axisSpacing.top + (i * spacing)) + ")"})
          .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
            .attr("dy","20px")
            .attr('class',"axis-text")
```

I'd like to apply multiple styles to the tick texts. One style for the first tick; another style, for ticks thereafter. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Select the text after it has been created and set the style accordingly.

Comment: OK. Once they're selected, I can access the individual text entries as unique `i` values, I assume?

Comment: You should be able to access everything in the usual way, i.e. `d` and `i` as data and index.

Comment: Solution posted below, which I think has wider application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided upon this solution:

```
d3.selectAll(".axis-text").style("text-anchor",function(d,i){ return i%2 ? "end" : "start"})
```

If you have two ticks on an axis, this places both tick labels on the inside of the axis length. See below:

[image]